# How to provide reference bean to XmlViewResolver

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i am generating Excel Sheet using Spring MVC , for this reason i have the following in my appcontext.xml file

**appcontext.xml**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/views.xml"/>

    </bean>
```

**views.xml**

```
<bean id="excelView" class="com.xxxx.xx.util.MyListExcelView" />
```

​

Instead of having the bean reference excelView in a  separate views.xml file .can we mention the below in the same appcontext.xml

```
<bean id="excelView" class="com.xxxx.xx.util.MyListExcelView" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can.

Just add [BeanNameViewResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/BeanNameViewResolver.html) to your ViewResolver chain.

Of course, you should remove `excelView` from `views.xml` in this case.

Here is an example:

appcontext.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="0"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/views.xml"/>
</bean>
<bean id="excelView" class="com.xxxx.xx.util.MyListExcelView" />
```

YourController.java

```
@Controller
public class YourController {
    // ...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    public String test() {
        // populate your model here
        return "excelView";
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: my question was can we completely avoid views.xml file itself ?

Comment: @Pawan , sure we can. If it is not used for anything else, you may freely remove `XmlViewResolver` and `views.xml`